# How to use trim() function in SSJS using data extension in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs

How do I use trim() functions in SSJS?  Using Data Extensions. Can you please provide some examples?

I have a Data Extension, where "Message" is an Attribute. In this Attribute how do I  use the trim() function for removing unwanted spaces?

Comment: Do not continue to post hostile and insulting comments against the contributors of SFSE.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**

So I have found out trim() is ECMA 5 and is not available as a native function in SFMC SSJS as that is based on ECMA 3 standards.  To be able to utilize, you can use this function to 'backfill' this capability in.

```js
  //Polyfill for trim
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
  };
```

which is utilized like so:

```js
var str = '     TrimMe      ';
var trimmed = str.trim();
```

---

**Original Answer**

Trim is a built in [Javascript function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp). The syntax is slightly different than AMPscript, but still simple.

You just use something like below:

```
var str = '     TrimMe      ';
var trimmed = str.trim();
```

Which would output: `TrimMe`

---

to remove all spaces in a string, you would need to do the following with a [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp):

```
var str = '  Trim Me  ';
var noSpace = str.replace(/ /g,'');
```

This would output: `TrimMe`

The `/ /g` is doing a global replace on all   characters. If you do with just `' '` it will only replace the first instance of the space.

Comment: good, But my idea is- For Example. in My Data extension Having Name = "test ABC Company", value is there. if i am using trim() function. i want to display Name = "testABCCompany". how to do using SSJS .

Comment: That is not a trim. Trim is only from front and end. I will adjust my answer to provide another solution for that shortly.

Comment: Thank you So much !!, for giving valuable Suggestion. If any solutions, Please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no **built in** function in **SSJS** that removes white spaces from a string.

However, you can use AMPScript's function [Trim()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Trim.htm).

In your case, it should be something like:

```
SET @message = AttributeValue("Message")
SET @trimmedMessage= trim(@message )
```

Comment: can you please give some more example...

Comment: Your question is not clear. You have 3 approches in 3 different answers. If you're not using AMPScript, check out the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to remove the spaces and keep the data in the data extension. When dealing with data extensions, I would suggest you to use SQL instead of SSJS. Extending following code, you will be able to create a Query Activity which reads and updates same data extension, keeping the Message clean from whitespaces, left and right. You need to combine both LTRIM and RTRIM as there is no dedicated TRIM function in the SQL version used in SFMC:

`SELECT fieldA, fieldB, RTRIM(LTRIM(Message)) AS Message from DataExtension;`

Operations on data within data extensions very rarely require SSJS, and also perform best when used in SQL.

Comment: i need to use in Cloud Pages using SSJS. not SQL. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Abdul_SFMC but why not fix the data quality once and for all? So you don't need to trim this string each time it is shown?

Comment: I Dont want Trim Each time. Once check with attributes, trim the data automatically. Example:: FirstName : Test  ABC, LastName = Company. this data Automatically Trim data.like TestABCCompany.

Comment: That is not trim. That's also not (only) removal of whitespaces. That is also concatenation. Please acquire a better understanding of programming, as SFSE is here to help you where you are stuck, and not provide complete solutions to unclear requests.

Comment: Okay, Thank you, Then how to use trim() using in SSJS. any examples.

Comment: What's wrong with Gortoningtons example?

Comment: Yes, I want some steps of  code.

Comment: One final note, as comments are not for prolonged discussions: 1: You are being unclear in what you want to achieve. 2: Gortonington has already provided an answer to your initial question. 3: Contributors on this forum expect whoever asks questions to do most of the work themselves, and help will be provided when they are stuck. 4: Please acquire basic understanding of SFMC development. Trailhead is a good place to start. 5: Come back to SFSE and ask questions with adequate details and proof of some initial effort from your side, and help WILL be provided.

Comment: @Abdul_SFMC - what other steps do you need? That is literally all the steps... I think LukasLunow is 100% right in his final note. This is a place for assistance and community growth, not a free agency to get your work done for you with no effort on your part.

Comment: @ Gortonington and @ Lukas Lunow Thank you guys. thank you for giving your suggestions.